# pandas pivot table calculate difference and sort result

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have a pivot table like this in pandas:

[image]

I want to add a column [DIFFERENCE] and sort the table by that new [DIFFERENCE] Column

I have played around with table.diff(axis=1) and but somehow don't get the sorting to work...

any idea is very much appriciated

Comment: Hi @user9093700. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) It also helps to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) showing samples of your input dataframes and expected output so that we can better understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a column based on the difference is very straightforward, sorting is possible by using `sort_values`

```
df['Difference'] = df['2021'] - df['2020']
df.sort_values('Difference', inplace=True)
```